# how to mount a range of drives in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, mount, block-device

I use something like this to unmount a range of drives:

```
umount /dev/sd[c-k]2
```

Is there any way to use same thing with mount? something like this:

```
mount /dev/sd[c-k]2 /[c2-k2]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Globbing (which is what you're doing with your wildcard matching) will expand the current command line.

For example:

```
ls [abc]1
```

gets expanded to:

```
ls a1 b1 c1
```

Globbing only works where the command allows multiple arguments. While `umount /dev/sdc2 /dev/sdd2` Works, there's no way to express the same thing for `mount`.

So you have to loop it:

```
for m in $(basename /[c-k]2)
do
  mount /dev/sd${m} /${m}
done
```

Comment: @alipoor.r: And if the paths are stable, edit `/etc/fstab` with the appropriate infos, and in the loop above just use `mount /dev/sd${m}` (ie, juste the source, no destination) and each time linux will look into /etc/fstab to know where that particular device should be mounted

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution using `xargs`:

```
echo -n {c..k} |
    xargs -d' ' -I{}  echo mount /dev/sd{}2 /{}2
```